# Lower bound for co-NP

Tags: complexity-theory

Suppose someone will prove lower bound (for NTM) for co-NP, say exp(n/d) for some constant d. Would it in some way imply lower bound (for DTM) for NP?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  If you can decide all languages in NP on a DTM in polynomial time, then P = NP = co-NP, i.e., you can also decide all languages in co-NP on a DTM in polynomial time, basically by negating the output of the DTM.  Taking the converse... if there exists a language $L$ in co-NP that can't be solved in polynomial time on a DTM, then there exists a language $L'$ in NP that can't be solved in polynomial time on a DTM (for instance, you can take $L'$ to be the complement of $L$).